# Can't mix OpenGL buffers and CPU buffers

Tags: opengl, opengl-compat

I have some code for a voxel engine that computes the outer faces of a chunk into a series of vertex, normals and texture coordinates arrays, and stores them on the CPU memory, so I can draw them.

After drawing them, I draw the selected face like a translucid red face, on top of everything.

It works, but as the world grows, it becomes slow; so I've started to do things right, generating buffers with `glGenBuffers`. This also works, but then the single face I draw after that disappears. I might also move it to a GPU buffer, but I would like to know why this is happening.

This is roughly the code I use to draw from CPU memory (it works, and it shows the selected face in red):

```
// Drawing the world, this is repeated for each chunk
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &mVertex[0]);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, &mNormal[0]);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &mTexture[0]);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, cVertex.size()/3);

// Drawing the selected face, face*12 or face*8 gives the correct index
glColor4f(1,0,0,0.2);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &boxVertex[face*12]);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, &boxNormal[face*12]);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &boxTextureCord[face*8]);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
```

Result (no textures):

[image]

Here I show the changes to draw from GPU memory (the selected face stops rendering):

```
// Drawing the world, this is repeated for each chunk
// Buffers have been previously filled with mVertex, mNormal and mTexture
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , mBuffers[0]);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, nullptr);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , mBuffers[1]);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, nullptr);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBuffers[2]);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, nullptr);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, cVertex.size()/3);

// Drawing the selected face, face*12 or face*8 gives the correct index
glColor4f(1,0,0,0.2);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &boxVertex[face*12]);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, &boxNormal[face*12]);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &boxTextureCord[face*8]);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
```

Result (no textures):

[image]

The only changes made are the ones showed here plus the code to call `glGenBuffers` and then copy the buffers to the GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL is a state engine. Once a state was set, it is kept, until it is changed again.

When you call [`glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mBuffers[2])`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindBuffer.xhtml), then the named buffer object `mBuffers[2]` is bound to the target `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`.
All the following calls to [`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml), [`glNormalPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glNormalPointer.xml) and [`glTexCoordPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoordPointer.xml) use this buffer and the last parameter to this functions is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store.

If you want to use the "CPU" buffer again and directly pass the memory address to those functions, then you've to unbind the current buffer by binding the value zero. After unbinding the buffer from the target `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, the last parameter specifies a pointer to the array of data:

```cpp
glColor4f(1,0,0,0.2);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // zero effectively unbinds any buffer object

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &boxVertex[face*12]);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, &boxNormal[face*12]);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &boxTextureCord[face*8]);

glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
```

Comment: Two for one, I also didn't know how to use an OpenGL buffer with an offset. Now it all fits. I had looked for a glUnbindBuffer type function but when I didn't find it I thought that the difference was in the use of nullptr.